# Slickgrid in the Android Browser (inner-div scrolling)

Tags: android, scroll, slickgrid

The Android Browser can't scroll inner divs.  That means using SlickGrid with its default configuration is impossible.

Fortunately, SlickGrid has an autoHeight argument that makes it not use inner scrollable content, so it works on the android.  Unfortunately, when autoHeight is enabled, onViewportChanged gets called once to span the entire viewport and is never called again, so it attempts to load all the data at once.  I'm lazy-loading and displaying so much remote data that if you try and load it all at once it crashes mobile devices, so that's a no go.

If SlickGrid were smart enough to know what's on the screen even if autoHeight is enabled, that would solve my problem.  I'd love it if that was a feature in core, since that would solve many problems on the desktop as well as on Android devices.

I also tried using [iScroll 4](http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4) to get around the Android limitation.  Unfortunately, it doesn't trigger onViewportChanged at all when I use iScroll.

I will probably have to solve this by ditching or modifying onViewportChanged to handle my own scrolling events.  I was wondering if there is an existing solution for this though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up writing [my own version of slickgrid](https://github.com/nickretallack/SlickGriddle) for this purpose.  Also, this will become irrelevant when Google Chrome becomes the default browser, as it actually has decent support for scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend using SlickGrid for apps/pages targeting mobile devices.  The grid was not developed with mobile devices in mind.  They require a completely different approach optimized for that particular use case.

Comment: I ended up modifying SlickGrid so that when autoHeight is set, it looks up to its ancestors to find the real scrollable viewport area and calculates what should be visible.  That way I could make the window scrollable and still get the benefits of slickgrid.  My modification is pretty hackish though, and messes with some of slickgrid's core assumptions, so it required me to change a lot of things.

Comment: Do you know of any better alternatives to slickgrid for mobile?

Comment: I think Grooveshark (which uses SlickGrid) has done a similar modification.  If you ever get to making this code more production-quality, it would be a great addition to SlickGrid.

Comment: I ended up tossing out my hacked slickgrid and just using slickgriddle for all my mobile needs.  I gave it an option to make the cells always as wide as the parent and all was good.