# Slickgrid mobile look

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slickgrid

Is it possible to change the look of a [Slickgrid](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/wiki) so that in a mobile application every row looks like a button? 
Also, seems like applying a formatter to a column (in order to put a button in it), like this:

```
function linkFormatter(row, cell, value, columnDef, dataContext) {
   return "<a href='myUrl' data-role='button'>View... </a>";
}
```

does not affect the appearence of the cell, and its content always looks like a normal link.
Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Slickgrid was not designed for Mobile clients. Refer to the answer for this question:

[Slickgrid in the Android Browser (inner-div scrolling)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10051694/slickgrid-in-the-android-browser-inner-div-scrolling)

and this URL too: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/slickgrid/eP7dhCo3ZhE/fnX-DV9mRxMJ